# How to delete/remove unfetched URLs from NUTCH Database (CrawlDB)

Tags: lucene, nutch

I want to crawl new URL list using nutch but there are some Un-fetched URL available :

```
bin/nutch readdb -stats

WebTable statistics start
Statistics for WebTable: 
retry 0:    3403
retry 1:    25
retry 2:    2
status 4 (status_redir_temp):   5
status 5 (status_redir_perm):   26
retry 3:    1
status 2 (status_fetched):  704
jobs:   {db_stats-job_local_0001={jobName=db_stats, jobID=job_local_0001, counters={Map-Reduce Framework={MAP_OUTPUT_MATERIALIZED_BYTES=227, REDUCE_INPUT_RECORDS=13, SPILLED_RECORDS=26, VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES=0, MAP_INPUT_RECORDS=3431, SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=1059, MAP_OUTPUT_BYTES=181843, REDUCE_SHUFFLE_BYTES=0, PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES=0, REDUCE_INPUT_GROUPS=13, COMBINE_OUTPUT_RECORDS=13, REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS=13, MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS=13724, COMBINE_INPUT_RECORDS=13724, CPU_MILLISECONDS=0, COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES=718675968}, File Input Format Counters ={BYTES_READ=0}, File Output Format Counters ={BYTES_WRITTEN=397}, FileSystemCounters={FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=1034761, FILE_BYTES_READ=912539}}}}
max score:  1.0
status 1 (status_unfetched):    2679
min score:  0.0
status 3 (status_gone): 17
TOTAL urls: 3431
avg score:  0.0043631596
WebTable statistics: done
```

So, How can i remove it from Nutch Database ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use CrawlDbMerger but you would only be able to filter by the URL and not the status, the Generator Job has already support for using jexl expressions but as far as I remember we don't have that feature built in now into the crawl DB.

One way would be to list all the URLs with the `status_unfetched` (`readdb`) and write some regex to block them (using the normal URL filter) then you just use the CrawlDbMerger to filter the crawldb with this filter enabled and your URLs should disappear.